# Primefaces: fileupload cursor issue

Tags: css, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, cursor

When I put the mouse cursor over the FileUpload button this is what happens: **the pointer type shows up only on the sides of the button but when it is over the label area, the cursor changes to type text**. The default FileUpload CSS appears to be fine, plus I haven't found any style option regarding the label or something similar that might be causing some friction.

[image]

**FileUpload default CSS**

```
.fileupload-buttonbar .ui-button input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 0 0 100px 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -o-transform: translate(250px, -50px) scale(1);
  direction: ltr;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 5000;
}
```

**XHTML**

```
<p:fileUpload style="pointer:cursor !important"
    fileUploadListener="#{controller.doSomething}"
    mode="advanced" label="Examinar"
    auto="true" 
/>
```

I tried overriding the CSS but no changes.

**NOTE:** This behaviour only happens with **Chrome** (default cursor) and **Firefox** (text cursor). Works fine on IE.

I've read about some cursor issues regarding datatable components but so far I haven't been able to get rid of this odd inconvenience.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you on your way with Chrome:

```
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button { cursor: pointer; }
```

Off the top of my head I think a fallback tactic worked for Firefox?:

```
input[type="file"] { cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; }
```

You might want to tag your answer with CSS as this is a browser styling 'thing'.

Comment: Thanks. It's working on Chrome now. Still no luck with Firefox. It seems to be a browser limitation. I found something similar here: http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/issues/detail?id=128